# Pygame sprite touching

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am attempting to build a simple game with two sprites. I can't figure out how to add code that detects if a sprite is touching the other. I am also having trouble understanding the countless tutorials on this topic. If you could try and explain this to me as simply as possible that would be amazing!

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
bg = black
square = pygame.image.load('square.png')
square1 = pygame.image.load('square1.png')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400))

UP = 'UP'
DOWN = 'DOWN'
LEFT = 'LEFT'
RIGHT = 'RIGHT'
direction = RIGHT
movex, movey, movex1, movey1 = 100, 100, 200, 200

class player1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Player 1"""

    def __init__(self, xy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('square.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class player2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Player 2"""

    def __init__(self, xy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('square1.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

while True:
    screen.fill(black)
    collide = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(player1, player2)
    if collide == True:
        print 'collision!'
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                movey -= 10 
            elif event.key == K_s:
                movey += 10
            elif event.key == K_a:
                movex -= 10
            elif event.key == K_d:
                movex += 10
            if event.key == K_UP:
                movey1 -= 10 
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                movey1 += 10
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                movex1 -= 10
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                movex1 += 10
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.blit(square, (movex, movey))
    screen.blit(square1, (movex1, movey1))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3):

Some issues first:

- `pygame.sprite.collide_mask` never returns `True`. It returns a point or `None`. So your check `collide == True` will never be evaluate to `True`
- `pygame.sprite.collide_mask` excepts two `Sprite` instances, but you call it with `class` objects as arguments (`collide_mask(player1, player2)`)
- You only need `pygame.sprite.collide_mask` when you want to do pixel perfect collision detection
- You actually don't use the classes `player1` and `player2` in the rest of your code

If you're using the `Sprite` class, a simply way for collision detection is to use the `Group` class. But since you only have two Sprites, you can simple check for an intersection of their `Rects` using [`colliderect`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).

I've updated your code to make use of the `Sprite` class:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

player1, player2 = Player('square.png', 100, 100), Player('square1.png', 200, 200)
players = pygame.sprite.Group(player1, player2)

while True:
    screen.fill(black)

    if player1.rect.colliderect(player2.rect):
        print 'collision!'

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                player1.rect.move_ip(0, -10) 
            elif event.key == K_s:
                player1.rect.move_ip(0, 10)
            elif event.key == K_a:
                player1.rect.move_ip(-10, 0)
            elif event.key == K_d:
                player1.rect.move_ip(10, 0)
            if event.key == K_UP:
                player2.rect.move_ip(0, -10)
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                player2.rect.move_ip(0, 10)
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                player2.rect.move_ip(-10, 0)
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                player2.rect.move_ip(10, 0)
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    players.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Collision detection is a broad topic, but this should get you started.